# search query in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am creating search query in php by passing variable through GET method. When the variable is null then it's passing the query like,

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE column_name = null`.

And it's showing error (obvious). I want to create query like. If user don't select anything from search options then it should fetch all the data from that column.

What's the correct logic for that?
Thanks.

Code:

```
if(isset($_GET['selPetType']) && $_GET['selPetType'] != '')
{
     $searchParams['petType'] = $_GET['selPetType'];
     $queryStr .= " PetType='" .$_GET['selPetType']. "'";
}

if(isset($_GET['txtPetBreed1']) && !empty($_GET['txtPetBreed1']))
{
    $searchParams['breed'] = $_GET['txtPetBreed1'];
    $queryStr .= " AND PetBreed1 ='". $_GET['txtPetBreed1'] . "'";
}


$clause1 = "SELECT * FROM pet WHERE $queryStr ORDER BY `Avatar` ASC LIMIT $startLimit, $pageLimit";
$totalRun1 = $allQuery->run($clause1);
```

Comment: Don't execute any SQL if nothing is being passed in the $_GET

Comment: Just don't use "WHERE" then in your SQL. Also, make sure to sanitize your user-input, you don't want any SQL injections.

Comment: If user selects petBreed then it will give me error. because the query statement starts with AND... there is no WHERE in the second query. AND if I am going to put WHERE overthere then if user selects 2 search options then WHERE will be 2 times in a query...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
    $get['param1'] = 'foo';
    $get['param3'] = null;
    $get['param2'] = '';
    $get['param4'] = 'bar';

    $where = null;

    foreach ($get as $col => $val) {
        if (!empty($val)) {
            $where[] = $col . ' = "' . $val . '"';
        }
    }

    $select = 'SELECT * FROM pet ';
    if ($where) {
        $select .= 'WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $where);
    }
    $select .= ' ORDER BY `Avatar` ASC LIMIT $startLimit, $pageLimit';
```

Edit: I added `if` to remove empty values and added 2 new values to example so you can see this values will not be in query.

Comment: I tried this.. For that I need to pass all get variables in to the $get array. But in some cases it could be null, If user don't select some search fields..

Comment: In that case, my query will become like: SELECT * FROM pet WHERE PetType = "dog" AND PetBreed1 = "" AND AgeType = "" AND PetGender = ""

Comment: I used this: $get['PetType'] = isset($_GET['PetType']) ? $_GET['PetType'] : false; But, I want all values if that field is null..

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_GET['your_variable'])){
  $whr = "column_name = $_GET['your_variable']";
}
else{
$whr = "1 = 1";
}

$qry ="SELECT * FROM table WHERE ".$whr;
```

Comment: column_name will be different everytime.. because, there are 7-8 search options.. Is there any way to make it dynamic?

Comment: Give the key of $_GET as the field name

Comment: If user selects multiple values then, thye query will be like, 
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column_name1 = 'abc' column_name2 = 'xyz';

There is no AND in between..

Answer (score 0):

For example :

```
<?php
    $userSelectedValue = ...;

    $whereCondition = $userSelectedValue ? " AND column_name = " . $userSelectedValue : "" ; 

    $query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1" . $whereCondition; 

?>
```

Then consider it's more safe to use prepared statements.